# How to send data from Form2 to Form1 into the Form1 TextBox when the button is clicked in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to send data from Form2 to Form1 but it doesn't work. I will just show the image so that you could understand what the problem is all about.

Here's the image: 
[image: Visual scenario of the problem]

The problem here is it doesn't work all. I cannot send the data to the Form1. How to make it work?

Here's the VB code for `AddLesseeForm class`

```
Public Class AddLesseeForm 'Form2

    'This is the Select Button
    Public Sub Button4_SelectLessee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4_SelectLessee.Click

        'Send data to AddData Form. The problem is it doesn't work
        Dim OBJ As New AddData

        OBJ.LesseeId = TextBox1_LesseeID.Text
        OBJ.LesseeName = TextBox2_LesseeName.Text

    End Sub
End Class
```

VB code for `AddData class`

```
Public Class AddData 'Form1

    Private Sub Button1_AddLesseeForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_AddLesseeForm.Click
        AddLesseeForm.Show()

    End Sub

    Public Property LesseeId As String
    Public Property LesseeName As String


    Public Sub AddData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       'Receive data from AddLesseeForm
        TextBox1_LesseeId.Text = LesseeId
        TextBox2_LesseeNm.Text = LesseeName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: We don't really see the full picture here, but `Dim OBJ As New AddData` creates a completely new `AddData` form. You should save the current instance at class level instead, then you'll be able to modify the currently opened one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to create an object of `AddData`, in VB.Net you can call with only name of Form, like that :

```
Public Sub Button4_SelectLessee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4_SelectLessee.Click

        AddData.LesseeId = TextBox1_LesseeID.Text
        AddData.LesseeName = TextBox2_LesseeName.Text
        AddData.UpdateData()
End Sub
```

and you can create a method for update data in `TextBox` in `AddData` Form like this :

```
Public Sub UpdateData()
    TextBox1_LesseeId.Text = LesseeId
    TextBox2_LesseeNm.Text = LesseeName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, setting your `LesseeId` and `LesseeName` properties won't update anything. Just because you're assigning them to somethig in the `Form Load` event it doesn't mean that they are bound to those controls.

Secondly, `Dim OBJ As New AddData` creates a **completely new** `AddData` form with it's own references. So you're setting the properties for a form that you never even show.

To solve this, you can show `AddLesseeForm` with it's owner set to `AddData`:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_AddLesseeForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_AddLesseeForm.Click
    AddLesseeForm.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

Now that `AddLesseeForm`'s owner is your `AddData` form, you can do like this:

```vb
Public Sub Button4_SelectLessee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4_SelectLessee.Click
    If Me.Owner IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Owner.GetType() Is GetType(AddData) Then
        Dim AddDataFrm As AddData = DirectCast(Me.Owner, AddData)
        AddDataFrm.LesseeId = TextBox1_LesseeID.Text
        AddDataFrm.LesseeName = TextBox2_LesseeName.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Which will get the owner (the current instance of `AddData`) and be able to modify it.

Lastly you should change the properties in `AddData` so that they actually update your text boxes:

```vb
Private _lesseeid As Integer = 0
Private _lesseename As String = ""

Public Property LesseeId As Integer
    Get
        Return _lesseeid
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _lesseeid = value
        TextBox1_LesseeId.Text = value.ToString()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LesseeName As String
    Get
        Return _lesseename
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _lesseename = value
        TextBox2_LesseeNm.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

VB code for `AddLesseeForm class`

```
Public Class AddLesseeForm 'Form2

        'This is the Select Button
        Public Sub Button4_SelectLessee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4_SelectLessee.Click

            AddData.loadLessee(TextBox1_LesseeID.Text, TextBox2_LesseeName.Text)

        End Sub
    End Class
```

VB code for `AddData class`

```
Public Class AddData 'Form1

    Private Sub Button1_AddLesseeForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_AddLesseeForm.Click
        AddLesseeForm.Show()

    End Sub

    Public Sub loadLessee(LesseeId As String, LesseeName As String)

        TextBox1_LesseeId.Text = LesseeId
        TextBox2_LesseeNm.Text = LesseeName

    End Sub

    Public Sub AddData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

First you place below code on send button click event:

```
    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim objtest As New test2(txtLesseeid.Text, txtLesseename.Text)
    objtest.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

On Second form where you want to get value you should place this code:

```
    Public Partial Class test2
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New(strtext1 As String, strtext2 As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        txtLesseeid.Text = strtext1
        txtLesseename.Text = strtext2
    End Sub

End Class
```